# Append text before and after container

Tags: css

How can i append text before and after the container as shown in the image below.

```
<div class="volume-container">  
  <div class="pb1">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my fiddle for the same.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cErwo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` in div. That makes div to act like a inline element but allows you to set element height. Another option would be using `float: left` and block level elements.. but this way is better:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hsFLi

**HTML:**

```
<div class="volume-container">
  <span>Pre</span>
  <div class="pb1">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <span>after</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.volume-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pb1 {
    width: 17.5%;    
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #dddddd;
  display:inline-block;
}

#progress-bar, #progress-bar2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #79a151;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [*-DEMO-*](http://codepen.io/kougiland/pen/Btndl)

You can just use [Pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on `.pb1` like this:

**Html:**

```
<div class="volume-container">  
  <div class="pb1">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First make sure that `.pb1` has a `position:relative` and use  `content:attr(data-percentage)" Usage";`

**Css:**

```
.volume-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pb1 {
    margin-left:100px;
    width: 17.5%;    
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #dddddd;
    position:relative;
}
.pb1:before,.pb1:after{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.pb1:before{
  left:-100px;
  content:"analysis volume"
}
.pb1:after{
  content:attr(data-percentage)" Usage";
  right:-100px;
}
#progress-bar, #progress-bar2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #79a151;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

then set `$('.pb1').attr('data-percentage',width);` to `.pb1`

**Js:**

```
var progressBar = $('#progress-bar'),
    width = 0;

progressBar.width(width);


var interval = setInterval(function() {
    width += 1;
    $('.pb1').attr('data-percentage',width);
    progressBar.css('width', width + '%');
    document.getElementById("progress-bar").innerHTML = width;
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```